# selecting rows of one dataframe using multiple columns of another dataframe in python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pick only **rows** from df1 where both values of columns A and B in df1 match values of columns A and B in df2 so for example if df 1 and df2 are as follow:

```
df1 
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8

df2
A B D E
1 2 6 8
2 3 7 9
4 5 2 1
```

the result will be a subset of df1 rows, in this example, result will look like:

```
df1
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[["A", "B"]], on=["A", "B"], how="inner")
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: df1.merge(df2[['A','B']]) will suffice, since default is inner and on all column.  Not that there's anything wrong w/your answer just in case anyone was curious about the default behavior.

Comment: @Chris Right :)

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSharma and Chris. I also have another question, is there an equivalent of "this" keyword for Pandas? For example, lets say I want to do df= df[df[c]>3] is there a way to do it in the same command as merge or as a chain command

Comment: @Mina Yes you can try, `pd.merge(df1[df1["C"] > 3], df2[["A", "B"]], on=["A", "B"])`

Comment: both great suggestions! Thanks a ton, honestly!